# Negating largest possible negative value in C

Tags: c

Is negating the integer `-2^(31)` defined as undefined behavior in the C standard or simply `-2^(31)` again? Trying it the latter holds, but it would be interesting to know how the C standard specifies it.

Comment: Depends on the exact code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. if I simply do `int y = -x` with `x = -2^(31)`

Comment: Since you are performing arithmetic operation here (unary `-` with `int` operand which is not promoted to any larger type), that leads to signed integer overflow, I'd say it is an undefined behavior. (this is true for 2's complement representation only)

Comment: C2x will mandate 2's complement, but doesn't address this UB

Comment: why would it be undefined behaviour on a machine where `int`is 64 bits ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean wrong ... `1` followed by `31` zeros is interpreted as `-2^31`

Comment: @CNTTT yes you're right

Comment: CNNTT, rather than using `-2^(31)` to denote the _largest possible negative value_ (for an `int`), simply use `INT_MIN` from `<limits.h>`.  That is less subject to misunderstanding. Note that the _largest possible negative value_ for an _integer_ is `INTMAX_MIN`, but I think you are casually making _integer_ synonymously with `int`.  Best to avoid that as it reduces clarity.  Be explicit by what you mean by _integer_.

Comment: Please show the code. The `x = -2^(31)` in comment does not compile, and `x = -2^31` is `-31`.

Comment: Edit the question to present the value properly. As Weather Vane alludes to, `-2^31` is the XOR of −2 and 31. And `1<<31` or `-1<<31` would have undefined behavior. The easiest way to rephrase the question may be by asking what is the behavior of `-INT_MIN` given that `int` uses two’s complement with no trap values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Interesting "... uses two’s complement with no trap values.".  I guess encoding with two’s complement does allow trap values as padding allowed and "Some combinations of padding bits might generate trap representations" -  A rare implementation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "And 1<<31 or -1<<31 would have undefined behavior" I'm a bit lost. Why is the first expression UB ? On ARM 32 bits and GCC, the first expression does not raise UB warning, the latter does though.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean: Essentially, left shifts that would shift a 1 bit into or out of the sign bit are overflow. Technically C 2018 6.5.7 4 defines left shifts only for nonnegative initial values that produces non-overflowed nonnegative results.

Comment: @EricPostpischil indeed i've found the exact statement in C99 standard: "The result of E1 << E2 (...) If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 x 2E2 is representable in the result type, then that isthe resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined". Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard (n2176 draft) says explictely at 6.5 Expressions § 5:

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not
> mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is
> undefined.

We are exactly there: the result is not is the range of representable values for the type, so it is explicitely UB.

That being said, most implementation use 2'complement for negative values and process operations on signed types as the operation on the unsigned type values having the same representation. Which is perfectly defined.

So getting `-2^(31)` again can be expected on common implementations. But as the standard says that it is UB, it cannot be relied on.

Comment: Many C implementations optimizing assuming undefined behavior never occurs (or may be replaced by anything when it does). Thus, in any loop where `x` starts at 0 and that only increments `x`, the optimizer may assume `0 < x` is always true, even if `x` actually overflows. Even if, when generating code to increment `x`, the compiler generates instructions that will wrap `x`, the compiler does not always generate such code—optimization may eliminate that. The resulting programs do not behave as if the implementation uses two’s complement for negative values.