# Why does exactly -LLONG_MIN lead to undefined behavior?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, integer-overflow, negation

Why does exactly `-LLONG_MIN` lead to undefined behavior?

C11, 6.5.3.3p3:

> The result of the unary - operator is the negative of its (promoted) operand. The integer
> promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.

Here we see that the C standard doesn't require that unary - operator to be implemented, for example, using bitwise-not followed by adding 1, where "adding 1" may lead to undefined behavior.

How to deduce from the quoted text that `-LLONG_MIN` leads to undefined behavior?

Comment: For all two's complement signed integer types, the negated minimum value cannot be held in that size of integer. For example `int8_t` the minimum value is `-128` and the maximum is `127`. The result is integer overflow, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Remember, the absolute value of the `<X>_MIN` signed integer types is (or can be thought of as) `<X>_MAX + 1`; therefore the negated min value leads to overflow.

Comment: Pmor, I would hope you would be acquainted with the C standard and how to read it. Did you not find https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p5 ? Do you know what has stopped you from finding it? Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301078/is-negating-int-min-undefined-behaviour or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71081310/why-does-int-min-int-min-and-how-the-negative-sign-operate-in-bit-level or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70758768/negating-largest-possible-negative-value-in-c answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to deduce from the quoted text that -LLONG_MIN leads to undefined behavior?

It is not possible to deduce it from the quoted text. You also need this text [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p5](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p5) :

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined.

On implementations in which the mathematical result of `-LLONG_MIN` is not representable in `long long` type, this rule is triggered and behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

> How to deduce from the quoted text that `-LLONG_MIN` leads to undefined behavior?

It cannot be deduced from the quoted text alone. However, this chain of reasoning suffices:

- The C standard permits `LLONG_MIN` to be −9,223,372,036,854,775,808 while `LLONG_MAX` is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (C 2018 5.2.4.2.1 1).
- There exists (in the mathematical sense) a C implementation in which `LLONG_MIN` and `LLONG_MAX` have those values. (I assume the reader is familiar with two’s complement and that the standard allows two’s complement.)
- In such a C implementation, the specified nominal result of `-LLONG_MIN` would be 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 (C 2018 6.5.3.3 3).
- The type of `LLONG_MIN` is `long long int` (C 2018 5.2.4.2.1 1), and the type of the result of `-LLONG_MIN` is `long long int` (C 2018 6.5.3.3 3 and 6.3.1.1).
- In said C implementation, that value would not be representable in `long long int` (due to the meanings of `LLONG_MIN` and `LLONG_MAX`).
- C 6.5 5 says:

> If an *exceptional condition* occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined.

Comment: It may be unexpected that 6.5.3.3p3 doesn't have the usual "If the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined." UPD. Ah, the 6.5p5 seems present to avoid the "If the result cannot be represented..." each time.

Comment: @pmor: That statement does not appear in any of the individual specifications of the operators. It is covered in the general statements for expressions, in 6.5 5 as I cited.

Comment: However, the "7. Library" does not have this "covers-all" mechanism. For example, C11, 7.22.6.1p2 has explicit "If the result cannot be represented..."

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have pointed out, this case is covered by paragraph 6.5-5 which says that the behavior is undefined if the result is not representable by its type.

Generally, undefined behavior may be a case where the behavior is simply not defined (mentioned) in the C standard, but in this case the standard is quite explicit.

When it comes to signed integer types, the C18 standard (and earlier) allows 3 representations (paragraph 6.2.6.2-2)

- Sign and magnitude
- Two's complement
- One's complement

With "two's complement" representation, the negative value of the minimal representable value is not representable (it will be one more than the maximal representable value).

With "sign and magnitude" and "one's complement", the negative value of the minimal representable value is representable (it will equal the maximal representable value).

Thus, `-LLONG_MIN` is undefined behavior if and only if the implementation uses the "two's complement" representation.

Since the Standard thus allows for implementations where this is undefined behavior, the behavior is undefined in terms of the Standard.

It is always allowed for an implementation to define behavior in cases where the behavior is undefined by the Standard, but in this case the Standard explicitly characterizes a group of implementations which have a defined behavior of `-LLONG_MIN` (those not using two's complement representation of signed integers).

It can be checked via a static assertion if the implementation has `-LLONG_MAX==LLONG_MIN`, but it is of little practical use since two's complement representation is by very far the most common.

The coming C2x standard will only allow two's complement representation (paragraph 6.2.6.2-2). So with C2x, `-LLONG_MIN` will always be undefined behavior in terms of the Standard.

Comment: Would the C2X standard preclude two's-complement implementations where the bit pattern associated with e.g. `~(unsigned long long)LLONG_MAX` would be a trap representation?  If a hardware platform had arithmetic instructions that would apply NaN semantics to that bit pattern, and a C compiler were to specify that signed arithmetic would be performed using such instructions, such a specification would be a useful form of conforming language extension that could greatly reduce the cost of overflow checking in many applications.